# Webpack CLI ignores .babelrc

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to use the wepback cli to do a build of a very simple script ... pretty much:

```
import 'somelib';
import '../mylib';
```

I'm running

```
webpack --output-filename index.js foo.js
```

But this gives me:

> ERROR in ./foo.js
>   Module parse failed: /dir/foo.js Line 1: Unexpected token
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   | import 'somelib';
>   | import '../mylib';
>   |

This indicates to me that webpack is not properly preprocessing the files, but I have a `.babelrc` in the same directory:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime", "transform-regenerator",
    "syntax-async-functions", "transform-async-to-generator"]
}
```

I do have the corresponding babel presets and plugins installed, and in fact `babel` does work properly on `foo.js`.

The documentation I found for both Babel and Webpack seem to say that it will use `.babelrc` automatically and I don't see any [cli flag](https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html) for webpack that would allow you to specify the babel configuration including plugins/presets.

Is there any way I can get the webpack cli to use the plugins and presets I specify in my `.babelrc`?

Comment: Did you add [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) to your webpack config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use babel with webpack you should install and register [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader).

`babel-loader` respects `.babelrc` file, so it won't require any additional configuration.

So, first you have to install it:

```
npm i babel-loader -D
```

Then you should either use an appropriate [`--module-bind` flag](http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#cli) in your CLI command:

```
webpack --module-bind 'js=babel' --output-filename index.js foo.js
```

or create webpack configuration file for your application (`webpack.config.js` or `webpack.config.babel.js`):

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: './foo.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }]
  }
}
```

so there will be no need to specify any command line arguments to build your project:

```
webpack
```

Comment: Do you know how I can specify the `exclude` piece from the cli?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, but why don't you want to use configuration file?

Comment: I want to be able to reuse the command one-liner in a bunch of different spots without necessarily recreating a config file for each one.

Comment: @ExplosionPills well, CLI arguments will overwrite whatever you'll put into configuration file. You can even omit `entry` and `output` blocks in your configuration file, so you'll be forced to specify them in your CLI command with every call.